# Problems with Standard I/O scanf

Tags: c

First, I just want to say that this is from an exercise in a book.  It is a very simple calculator.  The exercise specifically says to make this work using a goto statement (loop back to the beginning to enter another expression).  Both I and the author of the book know that goto statements are not generally a good idea.  I've written this little program but I can't figure out why I can't get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double num1 = 0.0;                  // first operand value a decimal number
    double num2 = 0.0;                  // second operand value a decimal number
    char oper = 0;                      // operator - must be +, -, *, /, or %
    char again = 0;

    // get the expression from the user
    Start: printf("\n\nEnter the expression: ");
    scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &oper, &num2);

    switch(oper)
    {
        case '+':                       // no checks necessary for addition
            printf(" = %lf\n\n", num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':                       // no checks necessary for subtraction
            printf(" = %lf\n\n", num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':                       // no checks necessary for multiplication
            printf(" = %lf\n\n", num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            if(num2 == 0)               // check second operand to see if it's zero
                printf("\n\n\aError:  division by zero!\n\n");
            else
                printf(" = %lf\n", num1/num2);
            break;
        case '%':
            if((long)num2 == 0)         // check second operand to see if it's zero
                printf("\n\n\aError:  division by zero!\n\n");
            else
                printf(" = %ld\n", (long)num1%(long)num2);
            break;
        default:                        // if we get here, it's an illegal operation
            printf("\n\n\aIllegal operation!\n\n");
            break;
    }
    printf("Do you want to perform another calculation?  Y/N: ");
    scanf("%c", &again);
    if((again == 'Y') || (again == 'y'))
    {
        printf("\n");
        goto Start;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first printf() and scanf() pair works fine.  However, the pair at the bottom doesn't work (below the switch statement).  It prints the text from the printf() function to the screen but then the program ends (I'm running it using the command line).  It does not allow me to type 'Y' to make it loop back to the beginning.  If I cut those 2 lines of code and paste them at the top, the program pauses and waits for my response just fine (it will let me enter a response).  I've moved the lines back and forth several times and I simply can't figure out why it works in one place but not the other.

P.S.  I have no wish to use goto statements but it irritates me that I can't figure out why I can't get this example from the book to work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `scanf` that's failing? Have you tried dumping the values of the variables directly after the `scanf` call?

Comment: or simply, check the return value of `scanf()`?

Comment: That looks as if the character scan retuned the new-line character after the original input. `scanf(" %c")` with a space before the format specifier may solve your problem. (In my opinion, a better solution is to use a two-spet input strategy: Read a line first with  `fgets` and then scan that with `sscanf`.)

Comment: I am 100% certain it is scanf() that's failing.  The printf() works fine.  For some reason, it's simply skipping the scanf() -- i.e. not waiting for me to enter a response.  If I move those two line to the top, it does pause and allow me to enter a response.  The only place it doesn't work is where I'm supposed to have it...at the bottom.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &again);`  --> `scanf(" %c", &again);`

Comment: M Oehm...yes, that worked -- adding the space.  Although I'm still not clear on why because the printf() right above it did not print a new line character.  Also, why did the exact same lines work at the top of the program when I cut & pasted them up there?  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf is always asking for surprises.

Comment: The functions of the `scanf` family don't know about lines. They treat new-line characters and tabs and spaces all as white space. They stop parsing where they left off, which is immediately after the second number and immedietely before a new line. The input doesn't have anything to do with output, by the way; they are two separate streams.

Comment: There's also the inconsistency that most formats (the numeric conversions and `%s`) ignore white space before conversion, but `%c` doesn't. The space means skip white space, if any, and so putting a space before the `%c` worked.

Comment: @Jens, right now, I'm just trying to get through the exercises without a lot of fluff.  However, I'm not new to programming (just new to C) and I was thinking about how to check that value earlier.  The book may cover it but I haven't got there yet.  Can I pass a callback of some sort to scanf() to do that or do I just have to save the value in a variable, check it and then flush the buffer, etc.?

Comment: @JosephMills Scanf either returns the number of chars read, or a negative number on failure. Changing your call of scanf to `if (scanf(" %c", &again) > 0;` Will check for failure.

Answer (score 3):

Your first `scanf` call reads a `double`, then a `char`, then a `double`. So if you type in `1.00+2.00` and then press enter, your input buffer `stdin` will contain this: `"1.00+2.00\n"`. The behaviour of the `scanf` family functions is such that it will remove from the input buffer only what it reads. After your first call to scanf the `stdin` buffer will contain `"\n"`

```
scanf("%c", &again);
```

Is reading a newline character `\n` left in `stdin`

Change it to

```
scanf(" %c", &again);
```

Pressing enter will always add a newline character to the input buffer `stdin`.

If you want to test the return vlaue of `scanf()` to cover additional input fails, you can do it like this:

```
if(scanf(" %c", &again) < 0)
{
printf("Error on scanf!");
}
```

[more info on the nucks and crannys of the scanf function.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Comment: No, I didn't want it to print a newline.  Now that I have it working, however, I'm trying to understand why there would be a newline character left in stdin???  Is it simply because I pressed enter to submit the expression at the top of the program?  i.e. if I scan more than one time in a program, there will always be a newline character to deal with after the first scan?

Comment: Yes, that newline character is caused by you pressing enter.

Comment: @JosephMills thats correct. Pressing enter adds a newline character to the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you guys so much.  I will keep that in mind for future.

Answer (score 1):

When you use scanf(), it reads formatted data from the stdin, and leaves the rest of the data to stdin so that subsequent scanf() calls can read it. In your case, the first scanf() reads the numbers, and leaves newline to stdin.

The next scanf() reads one character, and as stdin already has the newline in it, it reads the newline and doesn't ask any other input from you.

You can create a similar anomaly by adding two getchar() calls in a row, entering two characters and pressing enter. The second getchar() will not stop and ask you for input, because there is already enough input in stdin.

To fix this, you can change the first scanf() call to include newline (this assumes the user always gives a valid input):

```
scanf("%lf %c %lf\n", &num1, &oper, &num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a `getchar` like the following:
N.B: `getchar()` returns the first character in the input buffer, and removes it from the input buffer

```
 Start: printf("\n\nEnter the expression: ");
    scanf("%lf %c %lf", &num1, &oper, &num2);
    getchar();//inset this line
// rest of the code will same
```

need to `include<string.h>`